# SharePoint Online List View Filter makes excel export cap at 30,000 rows

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, export, export-to-excel

I'm using SharePoint online and my users and myself (SharePoint admin) are unable to export a list with more than 30,000 items if the list has a list view filter on it.

My users (standard O365 accounts) are unable to download over 30,000 rows regardless of whether it has a filter or the standard All items view (I am).

I need to change these options but I cant find them.

Answer (score 1):

There's a limitation on OOTB export to excel file function.

You could use following PowerShell to export list to excel file.

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/projects"
$ListName = "Projects"
$SelectedFields = @("ProjectName","Project_x0020_Manager", "StartDate")
$CSVPath = "C:\Temp\ListData.csv"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin
 
#Get List items from the list
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Fields $SelectedFields -PageSize 50000
 
#Iterate through each item and extract data
$ListDataColl = @()
$ListItems | ForEach-Object {
    $ListData = New-Object PSObject
    #Get the Field Values of the item as text
    $ListItem  = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $_ -Property FieldValuesAsText
    ForEach($Field in $SelectedFields)
    {
        $ListData | Add-Member Noteproperty $Field $ListItem[$Field]
    } 
    $ListDataColl += $ListData 
}
#Export data to CSV
$ListDataColl
$ListDataColl | Export-CSV $CSVPath -NoTypeInformation
```